# How to write "Degree" in a proper way while drawing a scatter plot in mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I want to draw a scatter plot of a equation which includes trigonometric \Sin[\theta] etc. Please show me the proper way to specify "Degree" while drawing the scatter plot. For Eg. if I write the command in this way, without specifying "Degrees" in Tab5, we get a different plot

```
m1[\[Phi]_,m31_, \[Beta]_, \[Theta]_, \[Alpha]_] := (Sqrt[m31])/(\[Sqrt](((-Sqrt[3] Sin[2 \[Alpha] Degree] Cos[\[Theta] Degree]^2 + 3 Sin[2 \[Theta] Degree] Sin[(2 \[Alpha] - \[Phi]) Degree] + 3 Sqrt[3]Sin[\[Theta] Degree]^2 Sin[2 (\[Alpha] - \[Phi]) Degree])/(3 Sqrt[3]Cos[\[Theta] Degree]^2 Sin[(2 (\[Beta] + \[Phi]) - 2 \[Alpha]) Degree] + Sqrt[3] Sin[\[Theta] Degree]^2 Sin[2 (\[Beta] - \[Alpha]) Degree] + 3 Sin[2 \[Theta] Degree] Sin[((2 \[Beta] + \[Phi]) - 2 \[Alpha]) Degree]))^2 - 1));
```

```
Tab5 = Table[{\[Phi], m1[\[Phi], Random[Real, {0.00247, 0.00263}],Random[Real, {0, 360}], Random[Real, {10.1  , 10.99}], Random[Real, {0 , 360 }]]}, {\[Phi], 0 , 360 , 1 Degree}];
```

```
Tab6 = DeleteCases[Tab5, {_?(150 < # < 220 &), _}];
```

```
P3 = ListPlot[Tab6, Frame -> { True, True, True, True},PlotRange -> {0, 0.3}, FrameLabel -> {\[Phi], m1},BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, PlotMarkers -> "+", PlotStyle -> Red]
```

While if we write "Degree" in Tab5 we get a constrained plot. For Eg

```
m1[\[Phi]_,m31_, \[Beta]_, \[Theta]_, \[Alpha]_] := (Sqrt[m31])/(\[Sqrt](((-Sqrt[3] Sin[2 \[Alpha] Degree] Cos[\[Theta] Degree]^2 + 3 Sin[2 \[Theta] Degree] Sin[(2 \[Alpha] - \[Phi]) Degree] + 3 Sqrt[3]Sin[\[Theta] Degree]^2 Sin[2 (\[Alpha] - \[Phi]) Degree])/(3 Sqrt[3]Cos[\[Theta] Degree]^2 Sin[(2 (\[Beta] + \[Phi]) - 2 \[Alpha]) Degree] + Sqrt[3] Sin[\[Theta] Degree]^2 Sin[2 (\[Beta] - \[Alpha]) Degree] + 3 Sin[2 \[Theta] Degree] Sin[((2 \[Beta] + \[Phi]) - 2 \[Alpha]) Degree]))^2 - 1));
```

```
Tab5 = Table[{\[Phi],m1[\[Phi], Random[Real, {0.00247, 0.00263}],Random[Real, {0, 360 Degree}],Random[Real, {10.1 Degree  , 10.99 Degree}],Random[Real, {0 , 360 Degree }]]}, {\[Phi], 0 , 360  , 1 Degree}];
```

```
Tab6 = DeleteCases[Tab5, {_?(150 < # < 220 &), _}];
```

```
P3 = ListPlot[Tab6, Frame -> { True, True, True, True},PlotRange -> {0, 0.3}, FrameLabel -> {\[Phi], m1},BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, PlotMarkers -> "+", PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Please suggest me what is the proper way to do.

Comment: It looks like you Tab5 has complex numbers in it.  Also, because your function is already converting everything to degrees, perhaps Tab5's range should be `{\[Phi], 0, 360, 1 }` instead of `{\[Phi], 0, 360, 1  Degree}`

Comment: While it works, it is unnecessary to use patterns and a function in your `DeleteCases[Tab5, {_?(150 < # < 220 &), _}]`, you could use `Select[Tab5, ! (150 < First[#] < 220) &]` or `DeleteCases[Tab5, {a_, b_} /; 150 < a < 220]` as alternatives.  This is just a programming style suggestion.